# TypeError: Query fields cannot be resolved. The type QuestionnaireType doesn't have a connection

Tags: python, django, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have the following schema:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_questionnaires = DjangoFilterConnectionField(QuestionnaireType)
```

I got the error when running the tests

> TypeError: Query fields cannot be resolved. The type QuestionnaireType doesn't have a connection

What can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to define a `Connection`, because for `graphene>=2` it is not done implicitly.

```py
class QuestionnaireConnection(graphene.relay.Connection):
    class Meta:
        node = QuestionnaireType
```